# PHP results not displayed in smarty template

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I have a variable `$my_arr` whose `var_dump($my_arr)` value is

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (9) { ["prod_index"]=> string(1) "1" ["prod_code"]=> string(4) "amp1" ["prod_name"]=> string(11) "Amplifier A" ["prod_price"]=> string(6) "100.00" ["frequency"]=> string(1) "2" ["gain"]=> string(1) "2" ["gain_variation"]=> string(3) "0.2" ["noise"]=> string(1) "2" ["power"]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#7 (9) { ["prod_index"]=> string(1) "3" ["prod_code"]=> string(4) "amp1" ["prod_name"]=> string(13) "Amplifire1.33" ["prod_price"]=> string(6) "133.00" ["frequency"]=> string(4) "2.12" ["gain"]=> string(1) "2" ["gain_variation"]=> string(3) "0.2" ["noise"]=> string(1) "2" ["power"]=> string(2) "10" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#8 (9) { ["prod_index"]=> string(1) "4" ["prod_code"]=> string(4) "amp1" ["prod_name"]=> string(13) "Amplifier1.45" ["prod_price"]=> string(6) "150.00" ["frequency"]=> string(4) "2.99" ["gain"]=> string(1) "2" ["gain_variation"]=> string(3) "0.2" ["noise"]=> string(1) "2" ["power"]=> string(2) "10" } }
```

In smarty I tried

```
{foreach name = fe1 item = k from = arr}
{$k->prod_index}    
{/foreach}
```

But it is not showing any result .

Comment: And how did you pass that variable from php to template?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from=$arr`? And as far as I know, in smarty 3 you can use PHP like syntax: `{foreach $arr as $k}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're already assigning the array to smarty like:

```
$smarty->assign( "arr", $my_arr );
```

You need to use the "." syntax, like:

```
{foreach name = fe1 item = k from = arr}
{$k.prod_index}    
{/foreach}
```

Comment: he is accessing an object's property not an array's key.. dunno if you can access them the same...

Comment: There is no "seamless" treatment of objects/arrays. Objects need ->, arrays need .

Comment: @rodneyrehm you can also access arrays like in PHP $arr['arrkey'] or $arr[arrkey]

Comment: I'm well aware of that, thx. But you can't with objects, which was the question I intended to answer :)

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I didn't notice the object within the array.